# "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]" while following tutorial

Tags: c

I was following a tutorial from the3dsage on youtube, and I got this error in the compiler:

```
D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  In function 'void init()':
354 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
355 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
356 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
357 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
358 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
359 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
360 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
361 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
362 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
363 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
364 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
365 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
366 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
367 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
368 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
369 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
370 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
371 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
372 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
373 20  D:\PERSONAL GAME DATA\cppProjects\helloWorld\gloom.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> 

#define res        1                        //0=160x120 1=360x240 4=640x480
#define SW         160*res                  //screen width
#define SH         120*res                  //screen height
#define SW2        (SW/2)                   //half of screen width
#define SH2        (SH/2)                   //half of screen height
#define pixelScale 4/res                    //OpenGL pixel scale
#define GLSW       (SW*pixelScale)          //OpenGL window width
#define GLSH       (SH*pixelScale)          //OpenGL window height

//textures
#include "textures/T_NUMBERS.h"
#include "textures/T_VIEW2D.h"
#include "textures/T_00.h"
#include "textures/T_01.h"
#include "textures/T_02.h"
#include "textures/T_03.h"
#include "textures/T_04.h"
#include "textures/T_05.h"
#include "textures/T_06.h"
#include "textures/T_07.h"
#include "textures/T_08.h"
#include "textures/T_09.h"
#include "textures/T_10.h"
#include "textures/T_11.h"
#include "textures/T_12.h"
#include "textures/T_13.h"
#include "textures/T_14.h"
#include "textures/T_15.h"
#include "textures/T_16.h"
#include "textures/T_17.h"
#include "textures/T_18.h"
#include "textures/T_19.h"
int numText=19;                          //number of textures
int numSect= 0;                          //number of sectors
int numWall= 0;                         

typedef struct 
{
 int fr1,fr2;           
}time; time T;

typedef struct 
{
 int w,s,a,d;           
 int sl,sr;             
 int m;                 
}keys; keys K;

typedef struct 
{
 float cos[360];        
 float sin[360];
}math; math M;

typedef struct 
{
 int x,y,z;             
 int a;                 
 int l;                 
}player; player P;

typedef struct 
{
 int x1,y1;             
 int x2,y2;             
 int c; 
    int wt,u,v;
    int shade;               
}walls; walls W[256];

typedef struct 
{
 int ws,we;             
 int z1,z2;             
 int d;                 
 int c1,c2;     
    int st, ss;        
 int surf[SW];          
 int surface;           
}sectors; sectors S[128];

typedef struct 
{
 int w,h;                             //texture width/height
 const unsigned char *name;           //texture name
}TexureMaps; TexureMaps Textures[64];

void load()
{
 FILE *fp = fopen("level.h","r");
 if(fp == NULL){ printf("Error opening level.h"); return;}
 int s,w;

 fscanf(fp,"%i",&numSect);   //number of sectors 
 for(s=0;s<numSect;s++)      //load all sectors
 {
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].ws);  
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].we); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].z1);  
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].z2); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].st); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&S[s].ss);  
 }
 fscanf(fp,"%i",&numWall);   //number of walls 
 for(s=0;s<numWall;s++)      //load all walls
 {
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].x1);  
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].y1); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].x2);  
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].y2); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].wt);
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].u); 
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].v);  
  fscanf(fp,"%i",&W[s].shade);  
 }
 fscanf(fp,"%i %i %i %i %i",&P.x,&P.y,&P.z, &P.a,&P.l); //player position, angle, look direction 
 fclose(fp); 
}

void drawPixel(int x,int y, int r, int g, int b)                  
{int rgb[3];
 glColor3ub(r,g,b); 
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 glVertex2i(x*pixelScale+2,y*pixelScale+2);
 glEnd();
}

void movePlayer()
{

 if(K.a ==1 && K.m==0){ P.a-=4; if(P.a<  0){ P.a+=360;}}  
 if(K.d ==1 && K.m==0){ P.a+=4; if(P.a>359){ P.a-=360;}}
 int dx=M.sin[P.a]*10.0; 
 int dy=M.cos[P.a]*10.0; 
 if(K.w ==1 && K.m==0){ P.x+=dx; P.y+=dy;}
 if(K.s ==1 && K.m==0){ P.x-=dx; P.y-=dy;}

 if(K.sr==1){ P.x+=dy; P.y-=dx;}
 if(K.sl==1){ P.x-=dy; P.y+=dx;}

 if(K.a==1 && K.m==1){ P.l-=1;}
 if(K.d==1 && K.m==1){ P.l+=1;}
 if(K.w==1 && K.m==1){ P.z-=4;}
 if(K.s==1 && K.m==1){ P.z+=4;}
}

void clearBackground() 
{int x,y;
 for(y=0;y<SH;y++)
 { 
  for(x=0;x<SW;x++){ drawPixel(x,y,0,60,130);} 
 }  
}

void clipBehindPlayer(int *x1,int *y1,int *z1, int x2,int y2,int z2) 
{
 float da=*y1;                                 
 float db= y2;                                 
 float d=da-db; if(d==0){ d=1;}
 float s = da/(da-db);                         
 *x1 = *x1 + s*(x2-(*x1));
 *y1 = *y1 + s*(y2-(*y1)); if(*y1==0){ *y1=1;} 
 *z1 = *z1 + s*(z2-(*z1));
}

void drawWall(int x1,int x2, int b1,int b2, int t1,int t2, int s,int w, int frontBack)
{int x,y;

 int dyb  = b2-b1;                       
 int dyt  = t2-t1;                       
 int dx   = x2-x1; if( dx==0){ dx=1;}    
 int xs=x1;                              

 if(x1<   0){ x1=   0;} 
 if(x2<   0){ x2=   0;} 
 if(x1>SW){ x1=SW;} 
 if(x2>SW){ x2=SW;} 

 for(x=x1;x<x2;x++)
 {

  int y1 = dyb*(x-xs+0.5)/dx+b1; 
  int y2 = dyt*(x-xs+0.5)/dx+t1; 

  if(y1<   0){ y1=   0;} 
  if(y2<   0){ y2=   0;} 
  if(y1>SH){ y1=SH;} 
  if(y2>SH){ y2=SH;} 
  
  if(frontBack==0)
        {
    if(S[s].surface==1){ S[s].surf[x]=y1;}
    if(S[s].surface==2){ S[s].surf[x]=y2;}
    for(y=y1;y<y2;y++){ drawPixel(x,y,0,255,0);} 
    }
    if(frontBack==1)
    {
        if(S[s].surface==1){ y2=S[s].surf[x];}
    if(S[s].surface==2){ y1=S[s].surf[x];}
    for(y=y1;y<y2;y++){ drawPixel(x,y,255,0,0);}
    }
 }
}

int dist(int x1,int y1, int x2,int y2)
{
 int distance = sqrt( (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) );
 return distance;
}

void draw3D()
{int x,s,w,frontBack,cycles, wx[4],wy[4],wz[4]; float CS=M.cos[P.a], SN=M.sin[P.a]; 

 for(s=0;s<numSect-1;s++)                                          
 {    
  for(w=0;w<numSect-s-1;w++)
  {
   if(S[w].d<S[w+1].d)
   { 
    sectors st=S[w]; S[w]=S[w+1]; S[w+1]=st; 
   }
  }
 }

 for(s=0;s<numSect;s++)
 { 
  S[s].d=0; 
       if(P.z<S[s].z1){ S[s].surface=1; cycles=2; for(x=0;x<SW;x++){ S[s].surf[x]=SH;}}  
  else if(P.z>S[s].z2){ S[s].surface=2; cycles=2; for(x=0;x<SW;x++){ S[s].surf[x]= 0;}} 
  else                { S[s].surface=0; cycles=1;}  
  for(frontBack=0;frontBack<cycles;frontBack++)
  {
   for(w=S[s].ws;w<S[s].we;w++)
   {

    int x1=W[w].x1-P.x, y1=W[w].y1-P.y;
    int x2=W[w].x2-P.x, y2=W[w].y2-P.y;

    if(frontBack==1){ int swp=x1; x1=x2; x2=swp; swp=y1; y1=y2; y2=swp;}

    wx[0]=x1*CS-y1*SN;                                                  
    wx[1]=x2*CS-y2*SN; 
    wx[2]=wx[0];                          
    wx[3]=wx[1]; 

    wy[0]=y1*CS+x1*SN; 
    wy[1]=y2*CS+x2*SN;
    wy[2]=wy[0];                          
    wy[3]=wy[1]; 
    S[s].d+=dist(0,0, (wx[0]+wx[1])/2, (wy[0]+wy[1])/2 );  

    wz[0]=S[s].z1-P.z+((P.l*wy[0])/32.0);
    wz[1]=S[s].z1-P.z+((P.l*wy[1])/32.0);
    wz[2]=S[s].z2-P.z+((P.l*wy[0])/32.0);  
    wz[3]=S[s].z2-P.z+((P.l*wy[1])/32.0); 

    if(wy[0]<1 && wy[1]<1){ continue;}      

    if(wy[0]<1)
    { 
     clipBehindPlayer(&wx[0],&wy[0],&wz[0], wx[1],wy[1],wz[1]); 
     clipBehindPlayer(&wx[2],&wy[2],&wz[2], wx[3],wy[3],wz[3]); 
    }

    if(wy[1]<1)
    { 
     clipBehindPlayer(&wx[1],&wy[1],&wz[1], wx[0],wy[0],wz[0]); 
     clipBehindPlayer(&wx[3],&wy[3],&wz[3], wx[2],wy[2],wz[2]); 
    }

    wx[0]=wx[0]*200/wy[0]+SW2; wy[0]=wz[0]*200/wy[0]+SH2;  
    wx[1]=wx[1]*200/wy[1]+SW2; wy[1]=wz[1]*200/wy[1]+SH2;
    wx[2]=wx[2]*200/wy[2]+SW2; wy[2]=wz[2]*200/wy[2]+SH2;  
    wx[3]=wx[3]*200/wy[3]+SW2; wy[3]=wz[3]*200/wy[3]+SH2;

    drawWall(wx[0],wx[1], wy[0],wy[1], wy[2],wy[3], s,w,frontBack);
   }
   S[s].d/=(S[s].we-S[s].ws);
  }
 }
}

void testTextures()
{int x,y,t;
    for(y=0;y<Textures[t].h;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<Textures[t].w;x++)
        {
            int pixel=y*3*Textures[t].w + x*3;
            int r=Textures[t].name[pixel+0];
            int g=Textures[t].name[pixel+1];
            int b=Textures[t].name[pixel+2];
            drawPixel(x,y,r,g,b);
        }
    }
}

void display() 
{int x,y;
 if(T.fr1-T.fr2>=50)                        
 { 
  clearBackground();
  movePlayer();
  testTextures();
  //draw3D(); 

  T.fr2=T.fr1;   
  glutSwapBuffers(); 
  glutReshapeWindow(GLSW,GLSH);             
 }

 T.fr1=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);          
 glutPostRedisplay();
} 

void KeysDown(unsigned char key,int x,int y)   
{ 
 if(key=='w'){ K.w =1;} 
 if(key=='s'){ K.s =1;} 
 if(key=='a'){ K.a =1;} 
 if(key=='d'){ K.d =1;} 
 if(key=='m'){ K.m =1;} 
 if(key==','){ K.sr=1;} 
 if(key=='.'){ K.sl=1;}
 if(key== 13){ load();}
}
void KeysUp(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{ 
 if(key=='w'){ K.w =0;}
 if(key=='s'){ K.s =0;}
 if(key=='a'){ K.a =0;}
 if(key=='d'){ K.d =0;}
 if(key=='m'){ K.m =0;}
 if(key==','){ K.sr=0;} 
 if(key=='.'){ K.sl=0;}
}



void init()
{int x;

 for(x=0;x<360;x++)                         
 {
  M.cos[x]=cos(x/180.0*M_PI); 
  M.sin[x]=sin(x/180.0*M_PI);
 } 

 P.x=70; P.y=-110; P.z=20; P.a=0; P.l=0;    
 Textures[ 0].name=T_00; Textures[ 0].h=T_00_HEIGHT; Textures[ 0].w=T_00_WIDTH; 
 Textures[ 1].name=T_01; Textures[ 1].h=T_01_HEIGHT; Textures[ 1].w=T_01_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 2].name=T_02; Textures[ 2].h=T_02_HEIGHT; Textures[ 2].w=T_02_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 3].name=T_03; Textures[ 3].h=T_03_HEIGHT; Textures[ 3].w=T_03_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 4].name=T_04; Textures[ 4].h=T_04_HEIGHT; Textures[ 4].w=T_04_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 5].name=T_05; Textures[ 5].h=T_05_HEIGHT; Textures[ 5].w=T_05_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 6].name=T_06; Textures[ 6].h=T_06_HEIGHT; Textures[ 6].w=T_06_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 7].name=T_07; Textures[ 7].h=T_07_HEIGHT; Textures[ 7].w=T_07_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 8].name=T_08; Textures[ 8].h=T_08_HEIGHT; Textures[ 8].w=T_08_WIDTH;
 Textures[ 9].name=T_09; Textures[ 9].h=T_09_HEIGHT; Textures[ 9].w=T_09_WIDTH;
 Textures[10].name=T_10; Textures[10].h=T_10_HEIGHT; Textures[10].w=T_10_WIDTH;
 Textures[11].name=T_11; Textures[11].h=T_11_HEIGHT; Textures[11].w=T_11_WIDTH;
 Textures[12].name=T_12; Textures[12].h=T_12_HEIGHT; Textures[12].w=T_12_WIDTH;
 Textures[13].name=T_13; Textures[13].h=T_13_HEIGHT; Textures[13].w=T_13_WIDTH;
 Textures[14].name=T_14; Textures[14].h=T_14_HEIGHT; Textures[14].w=T_14_WIDTH;
 Textures[15].name=T_15; Textures[15].h=T_15_HEIGHT; Textures[15].w=T_15_WIDTH;
 Textures[16].name=T_16; Textures[16].h=T_16_HEIGHT; Textures[16].w=T_16_WIDTH;
 Textures[17].name=T_17; Textures[17].h=T_17_HEIGHT; Textures[17].w=T_17_WIDTH;
 Textures[18].name=T_18; Textures[18].h=T_18_HEIGHT; Textures[18].w=T_18_WIDTH;
 Textures[19].name=T_19; Textures[19].h=T_19_HEIGHT; Textures[19].w=T_19_WIDTH;

 

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowPosition(GLSW/2,GLSH/2);
 glutInitWindowSize(GLSW,GLSH);
 glutCreateWindow(""); 
 glPointSize(pixelScale);                        
 gluOrtho2D(0,GLSW,0,GLSH);                      
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutKeyboardFunc(KeysDown);
 glutKeyboardUpFunc(KeysUp);
 glutMainLoop();
 return 0;
}
```

I tried switching the `const unsigned char *name;` to `const char *name;`, and got this instead in the console window that showed up:

```
Process exited with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This seems a far cry from a [mcve].

Comment: _"I tried switching the `const unsigned char *name;` to `const char *name;` ..."_ - Before making the switch, you had a compilation error. Now you've got a runtime access violation error. That is, a bug. Run the program in your debugger. If you use gcc or clang, you could also compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and it will probably give you hints about where to look for the bug. In MSVC, you could use [AddressSanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170)

Comment: after pressing the debug button in devc++, a box popped up saying : program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault., and it highlighted line 289, which had for(y=0;y<Textures[t].h;y++ on it.

Comment: `int x,y,t; for(y=0;y<Textures[t].h;y++)` - `t` has an indeterminate value since you didn't initialize it, so `Textures[t]` makes the program have undefined behavior. Enable more warnings and fix all warnings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For demonstrating your problem it would be sufficient to only show the first place where you get that error. You can just remove every repeated part of the code. That would make it much easier for everyone to read your code without wading through loads of redundant parts. There is no reason to show the same error 20 times. Please take that into account for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` field of the `TexureMaps` structure is used to point to pixel values, as can be seen in this function:

```
void testTextures()
{
    int x, y, t;
    for (y = 0; y < Textures[t].h; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < Textures[t].w; x++)
        {
            int pixel = y * 3 * Textures[t].w + x * 3;
            int r = Textures[t].name[pixel + 0];
            int g = Textures[t].name[pixel + 1];
            int b = Textures[t].name[pixel + 2];
            drawPixel(x, y, r, g, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The proper type for this pointer is `unsigned char *` or its `const` equivalent.  If you change the type to `char *` or `const char *`, the values read for the color components will be negative if the `char` type is signed by default, which is probably the case on your target system. You can silence the warning with explicit casts:

```
void init()
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < 360; x++)
    {
        M.cos[x] = cos(x / 180.0 * M_PI);
        M.sin[x] = sin(x / 180.0 * M_PI);
    }

    P.x = 70;
    P.y = -110;
    P.z = 20;
    P.a = 0;
    P.l = 0;
    Textures[ 0].name = (const unsigned char *)T_00; Textures[ 0].h = T_00_HEIGHT; Textures[ 0].w = T_00_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 1].name = (const unsigned char *)T_01; Textures[ 1].h = T_01_HEIGHT; Textures[ 1].w = T_01_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 2].name = (const unsigned char *)T_02; Textures[ 2].h = T_02_HEIGHT; Textures[ 2].w = T_02_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 3].name = (const unsigned char *)T_03; Textures[ 3].h = T_03_HEIGHT; Textures[ 3].w = T_03_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 4].name = (const unsigned char *)T_04; Textures[ 4].h = T_04_HEIGHT; Textures[ 4].w = T_04_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 5].name = (const unsigned char *)T_05; Textures[ 5].h = T_05_HEIGHT; Textures[ 5].w = T_05_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 6].name = (const unsigned char *)T_06; Textures[ 6].h = T_06_HEIGHT; Textures[ 6].w = T_06_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 7].name = (const unsigned char *)T_07; Textures[ 7].h = T_07_HEIGHT; Textures[ 7].w = T_07_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 8].name = (const unsigned char *)T_08; Textures[ 8].h = T_08_HEIGHT; Textures[ 8].w = T_08_WIDTH;
    Textures[ 9].name = (const unsigned char *)T_09; Textures[ 9].h = T_09_HEIGHT; Textures[ 9].w = T_09_WIDTH;
    Textures[10].name = (const unsigned char *)T_10; Textures[10].h = T_10_HEIGHT; Textures[10].w = T_10_WIDTH;
    Textures[11].name = (const unsigned char *)T_11; Textures[11].h = T_11_HEIGHT; Textures[11].w = T_11_WIDTH;
    Textures[12].name = (const unsigned char *)T_12; Textures[12].h = T_12_HEIGHT; Textures[12].w = T_12_WIDTH;
    Textures[13].name = (const unsigned char *)T_13; Textures[13].h = T_13_HEIGHT; Textures[13].w = T_13_WIDTH;
    Textures[14].name = (const unsigned char *)T_14; Textures[14].h = T_14_HEIGHT; Textures[14].w = T_14_WIDTH;
    Textures[15].name = (const unsigned char *)T_15; Textures[15].h = T_15_HEIGHT; Textures[15].w = T_15_WIDTH;
    Textures[16].name = (const unsigned char *)T_16; Textures[16].h = T_16_HEIGHT; Textures[16].w = T_16_WIDTH;
    Textures[17].name = (const unsigned char *)T_17; Textures[17].h = T_17_HEIGHT; Textures[17].w = T_17_WIDTH;
    Textures[18].name = (const unsigned char *)T_18; Textures[18].h = T_18_HEIGHT; Textures[18].w = T_18_WIDTH;
    Textures[19].name = (const unsigned char *)T_19; Textures[19].h = T_19_HEIGHT; Textures[19].w = T_19_WIDTH;
}
```

But a better fix would be to change the include files to use the proper type for the `char` arrays they define.

I would also recommend you add a `-funsigned-char` command line argument in your `CFLAGS` to make the `char` type unsigned by default.

I'm afraid this problem alone is not sufficient to explain the observed output, there must be other problems in the code provided or in the rest of the program.